# Add a link to each word from text

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I want every single word from a text to become a link, pointing to an URL customized by the word itself.

E.g.:
"I am Alberto"
should become:

```
<a href="example.com/I">I</a> <a href="example.com/am">am</a> <a href="example.com/Alberto">Alberto</a>
```

I'd start by the following but I have no idea how to go on

```
var text = $('textarea').html();
var words = text.split(' ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start. 
You just created an array of each word. 
Now you need to loop through every value in the array and output the html.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w798du6d/1/) to help you

Here's some simple code in jquery

```
  var text = $('.input').val();
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var link = "http://www.domain-name.com/";
  $.each(words, function(index, value) {
    $('.output').append('<a href="' + link + value + '">' + value + '</a> ');
  });
```